# Intercept / Decorate Entity Framework's DbContext.SaveChanges() through Simple Injector

Tags: c#, entity-framework, simple-injector

I am writing an AuditLog based on the changes tracked in the Context object in Entity Framework.

I need to be able to intercept calls to `Context.SaveChanges()`, as I then iterate through `Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and log these to my AuditLog.

I need to be able to do this on the `DbContext` itself as I both have the possibility to fetch a `DbContext` transiently directly and PerWebRequest through my UnitOfWork.

I have tried to address this through a decorator, which isn't working for me!

```
public class AuditLogSaveChangesInKNContextDecorator : DbContext
{
    DbContext _context;
    IHandleCommand<AddAuditLogEntriesFromTrackedChangesAndSaveChangesCommand> _handler;

    public AuditLogSaveChangesInKNContextDecorator(DbContext context,
        IHandleCommand<AddAuditLogEntriesFromTrackedChangesAndSaveChangesCommand> handler)
    {
        _context = context;
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changes = base.SaveChanges();

        _handler.Handle(new AddAuditLogEntriesFromTrackedChangesAndSaveChangesCommand { 
            Context = _context 
        });

        return changes;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing seems quite right to me. The only way to 'intercept' the call to `SaveChanges` is by overriding that method; it is virtual. For instance:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public event Action<MyDbContext> SavingChanges = _ => { };

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Notify objects that want to know, that we are gonna save some stuff
        this.SavingChanges(this);

        // Call the actual SaveChanges method to apply the changes to the database
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

By using an event, we can add any behavior (dependency injection) to the `MyDbContext` without that context having to know about it. For instance:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MyDbContext>(() =>
{
    var context = new MyDbContext();
    context.SavingChanges += UpdateEntities;
    return context;
});

private static void UpdateEntities(MyDbContext db)
{
    var addedEntities =
        from entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where entry.State == EntityState.Added
        select entry.Entity as IEntity;

    db.AuditTrailEntries.AddRange(
        from entity in addedEntities
        select new AuditTrailEntry 
        { 
            EntityId = entity.Id, 
            Type = entity.GetType().Name 
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `SaveChanges()`  on the wrong `DbContext`.

Instead of :

```
var changes = base.SaveChanges();
```

You should be using:

```
var changes = _context.SaveChanges();
```

Since `_context` is the `DbContext` that you're trying to track, you need to do the save on that one, instead of on your decorator object.